# How to zip two folders using ANT?

Tags: zip, ant

I want to zip two folders which are distinct in names in a base directory. Finally that zip file has to be present in the base directory. In this case, my destination directory is the base directory.

How could I do this in an ANT script?

Comment: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html

Answer (score 12):

Something like this should do it:

```
<zip destfile="${base.directory}/zipfile.zip"
   basedir="${base.directory}"
   includes="dir1/**,dir2/**"
/>
```

Comment: I guess this one is too old to get accepted, nevertheless it was exactly what I was looking for +1